# Hi, How do i get the response token from the URL in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How do I get the syskey_request_token from the below URL in selenium webdriver:
https://gimain03.uat.income.com.sg/insurance/mainMenu.do?syskey_request_to
ken=2b7c09eda6d7acf3b95b6745152cf521

Comment: `WebDriver#getCurrentUrl` -> split the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to handle this, like:

```
import re 

currentPageUrl = driver.current_url
syskey_request_token = re.findall('syskey_request_token=.*', currentPageUrl)[0]
```

Comment: in the above code, I am getting error "Cannot resolve method findall" and  for syskey_request_token " too many characters in character literal" .

Comment: The OP is using Java, not Python.

Answer (score 0):

Me again, just a little misunderstanding, here is solution in Java:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openChrome();
    }
    /**
     * open chrome driver
     */
    public static void openChrome() {
        // path of driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Typing your URL below
        driver.get("xxx://xxx.xxx.xxx");
        String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        // Using regex to find key 'syskey_request_token='
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("syskey_request_token=(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currentURL);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.print(currentURL+"\n");
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1)+"\n");
    }
}
```